# Which Stack Overflow table saves the data for accepted answers?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, data-explorer

I'm studying the tables that are provided by the Data Explorer for Stack Overflow. In the table `Post` there is a column called `AcceptedAnswerID`, but there is not an `AcceptedAnswer` table. So where is the answer stored when a user replies to a question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the `Posts` table contains entries for both questions and answers (distinguished by their `Posts.PostTypeId`), to get the accepted answer for the current question you'll have to perform a `JOIN` on `Posts.AcceptedAnswerId` and `Posts.Id`, setting `Posts.PostTypeId = 2` to get posts of type `Answer`.

Below is the query to retrieve the answer count and the id of the accepted answer in raw data form, for the post with the given id:

```
SELECT Posts.AnswerCount, Posts.AcceptedAnswerId
FROM Posts
WHERE 
  Posts.Id = 19628880;
```

[You can find the whole query, forkable and modifyable, on Data Explorer here.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/321341/accepted-answer-and-answer-count-for-postid-19628880)

Comment: Thanks for your answer i have upvote your answer and mark as correct . Thanks again

Comment: @A.Goutam See my edit for the query and the link on DataExchange.